# Represent 9999999999999999 in actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, numbers

I tried storing 10<sup>16</sup> - 1 in a `Number` variable:

```
var n:Number = 9999999999999999
```

but the value stored in `n` ends up being 10000000000000000, or 10<sup>17</sup>.

How can I represent 10<sup>16</sup> - 1 in actionscript 3?

Answer (score 17):

You've ran out of Number type precision capability, so you'll have to devise your own way to store numbers this big with the required precision. One of the most common way to operate long arithmetic is using strings as data holders, another is using a vector of ints, each position representing a "big digit" of a 2^32 based system. Given AS3 constraints, I'd say a vector of ints would be faster, although displaying a long number will be easier with string based approach.

Comment: + 1 for correct answer There are some readymade implementations of this. For example http://www.graniteds.org/confluence/display/DOC/2.+Big+Number+Implementations

Comment: Yes but a theoretical explanation of why it is happening is one thing. Hence, the addition of a fix/workaround for his problem for completeness of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as a "Number" type can hold a few digits more than you are trying to put in it, I think it's more of a miscalculation.  9,999,999,999,999,999 is actually 10^17 - 1, I would honestly guess that you got some parenthesis wrong or didn't parse the equation quite right and maybe what you wanted as (10^16) - 1 ended up executing more as 10^(16-1).  I tend to err more to the side of caution when having equations like that and put in a lot more parenthesis than I need sometimes.  I think I had a bad experience with order of operations in AS3 one time and am now OCD about it when coding.

I know this question is super old, but I felt like it could use some clarifying.  The Number type can hold I think 18,446,744,073,709,551,616 that is 64 bit as I found out from searching the internet.  That is also 20 digits, so more than enough.