# Casting large numbers as string to number in actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, numbers

For some values, such as "10152116260776319", casting to number with parseFloat or Number("***") methods increments the original value by 1.

```
Number("10152116260776319") => 10152116260776320
Number("10202784509328139") => 10202784509328140
```

Is there any way to fix this? Or do I need to update all of my code to Strings.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12742177/represent-9999999999999999-in-actionscript-3 You've hit precision wall in here, so if you need to maintain precision to the last digit, do use an implementation of very big integers, regardless of its internal structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is not due to a problem with `parseFloat` or `Number("***")`, but a limitation of the `Number` type. Basically, the `Number` type can only hold integers properly if they're below 2<sup>53</sup> (9,007,199,254,740,992), because they're double precision floating point numbers (check out this Wikipedia page for more details: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)

The problem occurs even without casting, for example

```
var val1:Number = 9007199254740990;
var val2:Number = 9007199254740991;
var val3:Number = 9007199254740992;
var val4:Number = 9007199254740993;
var val5:Number = 9007199254740994;

var val6:Number = 10152116260776319;

trace(val1); // 9007199254740990
trace(val2); // 9007199254740991
trace(val3); // 9007199254740992
trace(val4); // 9007199254740992
trace(val5); // 9007199254740994
trace(val6); // 10152116260776320
```

If you really need to store integers that large, someone's made a `BigInt` class that you can use: http://as3asclublib.googlecode.com/svn-history/r29/trunk/data/BigInt.as

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will convert all to Strings.